В чем проблема импорта?
Есть такой код:
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

from dotenv import load_dotenv

def main():
    load_dotenv()

    g_walk = ox.graph_from_place('Manhattan Island, New York City, New York, USA',
                         network_type='walk')

    orig_node = ox.nearest_nodes(g_walk,
                            40.748441, -73.985664)

    dest_node = ox.nearest_nodes(g_walk,
                            40.748441, -73.4)

    route = nx.shortest_path(g_walk,
                     orig_node,
                     dest_node,
                     weight='length')

    route_map = ox.plot_route_folium(g_walk, route)

    route_map.save('map.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

При выполнении данного скрипта через некоторое время выдает данное исключение:
orig_node = ox.nearest_nodes(g_walk,
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: scikit-learn must be installed to search an unprojected graph

Хотя в виртуальном окружении и в общем данная библиотека стоит.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212987/cannot-import-scikits-learn-even-though-it-seems-to-be-installed
